# Why do I get different results when I use twitteR to search for tweets by location

Tags: r, twitter

I am using the twitteR R package to search for tweets by keyword. The function searchTwitter() allows you to search with or without a location specified. If you specify a location it returns tweets within a radius, or else it returns all tweets with the keyword.

I have limited my search to just one or two days and I am searching all the locations globally where the keywords that I am interested in would be tweeting from but I get many more tweets with the general search (i.e. without location) than if I search by location and add up the tweets from all the cities around the world which are likely giving tweets. I was not expecting the same number exactly but I am way off.

Am I missing something with this function or is it not possible to get the location of some tweets?

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted???

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that shows the code you are running and how you are comparing results. Twitter does not let you query all tweets; there is limited data available via the API. The "standard" API has "Incomplete" data fidelity.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, I understand that a reproducible example would be helpful but in this case the question is quite general, but I think quite clear. Are you not allowed ask questions here?

Comment: The help section tells you [what types of questions are on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. As stated there, questions about why code doesn't return the expected results are expected to contain the code used. Or maybe remove the "R" tag if this doesn't have to do with R code specifically.